# Filter huge records (30k-50k) + in angular using lodash in angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter

Scenario:
I am fetching records around 50k through APIs. Each record in this has a Datetime field like this.

```
{
    "ID": 7,
    "CaseID": 7,
    "Name": "ABC",
    "DateTime": "2020-02-25 00:00:00.000",
  },
  {
    "ID": 8,
    "CaseID": 8,
    "Name": "Skin",
    "DateTime": "2020-03-12 00:00:00.000",
  }
```

On UI, I have a dropdown that filters data based on the current quarter, last quarter, this month, last year, last month, etc and a custom range datepicker.

On the Selection of any option, I have a filter function which filters this huge record based on the start and end date of the option selected.
For example, the Current Quarter then, Start Date of the quarter and end date of Quarter.

Filter function just checks if the records date Is falling under the range of the option selected.
My Code:

```
const filteredData = _.filter(hugeRecords, record => {
      const visualDate = moment(record.DateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      return moment(visualDate).isBetween(this.periodTitleStartDate, this.periodTitleEndDate);
    });
```

where periodTitleStartDate and periodTitleEndDate is the range of dropdown option selected in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Now the problem is if I have records of around 10k then no issue. If records are around 20k, UI hangs a little bit. If records are 30k-50k, Browser UI hangs for longer.
Furthermore, I will use this filtered array to pass into highcharts to create charts in my dashboard view.

I tried many terms and other StackOverflow and Github questions/issues but not able to solve my problem.
How can I improve the performance of filtering?
Note: Passing dropdown option to rest API and fetch only filtered records is not an option for now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your filtering process can be more efficient with preprocessing and possibly pre sorting could enable a binary search approach to be hyper efficient (though maybe not worth it if you’ll have to change the sort of the result after). But 50k honestly isn’t that high and on the front end usually the source of performance issues is in rendering. Are you attempting to render 50k records at once? Or are they paged / are you using virtual scrolling?

Comment: @bryan60 No. Out of 50K records, I am filtering based on date range selected and I am passing this array to charts ( highcharts ) and also showing some calculated values with charts in a KPI.

Comment: @bryan60 if you can just help me out with the best approach to filter above-written code by providing some sample code, I would be glad as I am kinda new to angular here.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could preprocess the array to have the calculated timestamp. This only has to be done once.

Then the filter will only compare numbers (timestamps) and speed up the process a lot.

Also you could then sort the array by timestamp and thus do a lot of improvements when searching between dates.

```
// Preprocess

const processed = Records.map( record =>{
record.timestamp = moment(record.DateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD').unix();
```

return record;
    });

```
// Filter assuming you have converted the boundary Dates to timestamps with moment and unix().

const filtered = processed.filter( record => {
 return !(this.periodTitleStartDate < record.timestamp &&  this.periodTitleEndDate > record.timestamp
});
```

Comment: Preprocessing the dates is definitely a gain but Sorting would only definitely improve efficiency if the array is intended to be sorted by date time. Filtering on a range of an Unsorted array is O(N) complexity. Filtering on a range of a sorted array is O(2log(N)) for 2 binary searches. But if you have to sort it again after it adds in Mlog(M) where M is the number of results. For any significant M, that will be less efficient than just N.

Comment: Okay. got your answer. Actually, this is what I am doing. First I am filtering data based on preset selected and then doing my remaining process on the filtered data ( calculating and showing the charts ). But the problem is,  during the first filter only, it is taking much time and hanging the browser. The records increases, it hangs more.

Comment: Well my proposal was to do a map first doing only the transformation to timestamp and then filtering with only the timestamp comaprison.

Comment: @satchcoder could you please provide me a sample code here in your answer. I would be grateful.

Comment: Take it just as an example..I dont have the laptop here so Im editing from mobile phone

Comment: also convert `periodTitleStartDate` and `periodTitleEndDate` to timestamps one time prior to running the filter rather than in every iteration of the filter.

Comment: I can't do as mentioned in the answer using map function. It will only return timestamp. Although after filter I want to use other properties of the object for calculation and building charts. timestamp is the main object property on which filter should happen and then use business logic on filtered data which used other properties of the object like id, name, etc.

Comment: Datepicker with presets like last month, last quarter, this quarter, etc. are on top of the app. It is a shared component. When date range changes , each KPI subscribe to it, and then start filtering data based on the date range selection. I am using subscribe for doing that in each KPI. When data is 10k+, dropdown hangs a little and each KPI rendering also. Can it also be related to subscription or RXJS ?

Comment: I edited.the code. The map has to return the record object.